# When do I get skill points?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm level 7 or 8 and I've only gotten three skill points so far. In Borderlands 1 you got a skill point every level up. At what rate do you get skill points in Borderlands 2? Every other level or what? What will I max out at?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just like Borderlands 1 before it, you accumulate one skill point per level **starting at level 5** (you must acquire your Action Ability with your first point).